# How to write a differential equation using polar coordinates?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates, laplacian

How is the differential equation $\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2} + \frac{∂^2f}{∂y^2} = 0$ transformed  if you switch to polar coordinates, x = r cos θ, y = r sin θ?
I have done everything right except $\frac{∂^2f}{∂\theta^2}$ (I hope you can see it clearly):
[image]
However this is how they did $\frac{∂^2f}{∂\theta^2}$ in my book:
[image]

The thing I don't understand is where they get $-r\frac{∂z}{∂r}$ from in their solution for $\frac{∂^2f}{∂\theta^2}$? Or is my answer correct? Did I answer what I was asked?

Comment: How do you come up with your first equality?

Comment: The first result proposed to me by Google explains exactly how to do this:https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~saito/courses/21C.w11/polar-lap.pdf